# Optional arguments in completionHandler

Tags: ios, swift

I want to pass for my `completionHandler` default argument:

```
func firstFunc(completionHandler: ((array:[String:AnyObject] = [:]) -> Void)?)) {

    }
```

But get error:

> Default argument not permitted in a tuple type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler error is misleading. It has nothing to do with tuples. Here is how to provide default closure value. Define your function like this:

```
func firstFunc(completionHandler:(([String:AnyObject]) -> Void?) = { _ in return }) {
}
```

`{ _ in return }` is the default value there. This is what will work now:

```
firstFunc() // uses default closure value

firstFunc { (completionHandler: [String : AnyObject]) -> Void? in
    return
}
```